# Converting pandas data frame logic to pyspark data frame based logic

Tags: pandas, pyspark, logic

Given a  data frame with 4 columns `group`, `start_date`, `available_stock`, `used_stock`.
 I basically have to figure out how long a stock will last given a group and date. lets say we have a dataframe with the following data

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
|  group   | start_date | available stock | used_stock |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
| group 1  | 01/12/2019 |             100 |         80 |
| group 1  | 08/12/2019 |              60 |         10 |
| group 1  | 15/12/2019 |              60 |         10 |
| group 1  | 22/12/2019 |             150 |        200 |
| group 2  | 15/12/2019 |              80 |         90 |
| group 2  | 22/12/2019 |             150 |         30 |
| group 3  | 22/12/2019 |              50 |         50 |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Steps:

1. sort each group by start_date so we get something like the above data set
2. per group starting from the smallest date we check if the used_stock is greater or equal to the  available stock. if it is true the end date is same as start_date
3. if the above condition is false then add the next dates used_stock to the current used_stock value. continue till the used_stock is greater or equal to available_stock, at which point the end date is same as the start_date of last added used_stock row.
4. in case no such value is found end date is null

after applying the above steps for every row we should get something like

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
|  group   | start_date | available stock | used_stock |  end_date  |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
| group 1  | 01/12/2019 |             100 |         80 | 15/12/2019 |
| group 1  | 08/12/2019 |              60 |         10 | 22/12/2019 |
| group 1  | 15/12/2019 |              60 |         10 | 22/12/2019 |
| group 1  | 22/12/2019 |             150 |        200 | 22/12/2019 |
| group 2  | 15/12/2019 |              80 |         90 | 15/12/2019 |
| group 2  | 22/12/2019 |             150 |         30 |     null   |
| group 3  | 22/12/2019 |              50 |         50 | 22/12/2019 |
+----------+------------+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

the above logic was prebuilt in pandas and was tweaked and applied in the spark application as a **grouped map Pandas UDF**. 
 I want to move away from @pandas_udf approach and have a pure spark data frame based approach to check if there will be any performance improvements.
Would appreciate any help with this or any improvements on the given logic which would reduce the overall execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With spark 2.4+, you can use SparkSQL builtin function [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate):

```
aggregate(array_argument, zero_expression, merge, finish)
```

and implement the logic in the *merge* and *finish* expressions, see below for an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct, to_date, expr
from pyspark.sql import Window

w1 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('start_date').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

# SQL expression to calculate end_date using aggregate function:
end_date_expr = """

    aggregate(
      /* argument */
      data,
      /* zero expression, initialize and specify the aggregator's datatype which is 'struct<end_date:date,total:double>' */
      (date(NULL) as end_date, double(0) as total),
      /* merge: use acc.total to save accumulated sum of used_stock
       * this works similar to Python's reduce function
       */
      (acc, y) ->
        IF(acc.total >= `available stock`
        ,  (acc.end_date as end_date, acc.total as total)
        ,  (y.start_date as end_date, acc.total + y.used_stock as total)
        ),
      /* finish: post-processing and retrieving only end_date */
      z -> IF(z.total >= `available stock`, z.end_date, NULL)
    )

"""

df.withColumn('start_date', to_date('start_date', 'dd/MM/yyyy')) \
    .withColumn('data', collect_list(struct('start_date','used_stock')).over(w1)) \
    .withColumn('end_date', expr(end_date_expr)) \
    .select("group", "start_date", "`available stock`", "used_stock", "end_date") \
    .show(truncate=False)
+-------+----------+---------------+----------+----------+
|group  |start_date|available stock|used_stock|end_date  |
+-------+----------+---------------+----------+----------+
|group 1|2019-12-01|100            |80        |2019-12-15|
|group 1|2019-12-08|60             |10        |2019-12-22|
|group 1|2019-12-15|60             |10        |2019-12-22|
|group 1|2019-12-22|150            |200       |2019-12-22|
|group 2|2019-12-15|80             |90        |2019-12-15|
|group 2|2019-12-22|150            |30        |null      |
|group 3|2019-12-22|50             |50        |2019-12-22|
+-------+----------+---------------+----------+----------+
```

**Note:** this could be less efficient if many of the groups contain a large list of rows(i.e. 1000+ rows), when most of them require to just scan limited rows (i.e. less than 20) to find the first row satisfying the condition. In such case, you might set up two Window specs and do the calculation in two rounds:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct, to_date, col, when, expr

# 1st scan up to the N following rows which can cover majority of end_date satisfying the condition
N = 20
w2 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('start_date').rowsBetween(0, N)

# 2nd scan will cover the full length but only to rows having end_date is NULL
w1 = Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('start_date').rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn('start_date', to_date('start_date', 'dd/MM/yyyy')) \
    .withColumn('data', collect_list(struct('start_date','used_stock')).over(w2)) \
    .withColumn('end_date', expr(end_date_expr)) \
    .withColumn('data',
       when(col('end_date').isNull(), collect_list(struct('start_date','used_stock')).over(w1))) \
    .selectExpr(
       "group",
       "start_date",
       "`available stock`",
       "used_stock",
       "IF(end_date is NULL, {0}, end_date) AS end_date".format(end_date_expr)
    ).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: the lead would give me the next date but i need to get the next date when the cumulative sum of my used_stock becomes greater than the available stock. I have edited the example in the question to show this. If we look at the first row the available_stock is 100 and used_stock is 80, so i keep on adding to used stock till it becomes >= available_stock. In this case till 15/12/2019 (80+10+10).

Comment: can you use spark 2.4+?

Comment: Yes, the spark environment can be changed as per requirement